# Add button for publishing questions (and answers?) on facebook(/Twitter/whatever)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, facebook, social-networking, sharing

Sometimes, especially with niche or otherwise tricky questions, I'd like to increase posts' visibility as much as possible. One approach I've taken for this is posting a link to the question as a facebook status update.

I think it would be great if that functionality were integrated directly with the question/answer posting form ***similar to the way I can currently share projects I follow/commit to on Area 51***.

Comment: (concerning your edited-out part, you could use [your rss feed](http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/9784))

Comment: @Tobias: You should have read all of the edited-out part. ;) I explained why I didn't see the user rss feed (in its current form) as an option, namely that I want to remain in control over the privacy options and that I really only want questions, not answers and most certainly not comments to be shared.

Comment: sorry, yes, I kind of missed that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is available now:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/

Comment: It might be on some of the SE sites but it isn't on stackoverflow.com as far as I can tell...

Comment: We need the +1 button now